# Angular entryComponents input to directive binding

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have an existing button component A that I want to use in [another](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table) (3rd party) component B. The component B expects A to be [passed by type](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-is-an-entry-component) so I added it to the `entryComponents` list of my module. So far so good.

The component B expects A to have 2 inputs named `value` and `rowData`. I want this `value` to appear as `someLabel` and would be happy with using the same `someIcon` for all instances of component A within component B.

Component B [exposes](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation) 2 callbacks:

- `onComponentInitFunction: (instance: any) => { ... }` gets called 1st and returns an instance of component A that can be used to setup listeners for component A's outputs.
- `valuePrepareFunction: (cell: string|number, row: any) => { ... }` gets called 2nd and can be used to compute a desired return `value` based on input `row` data.

**Question** Can I reuse component A as it is, possibly taking advantage of component B callbacks to map `value` to `someLabel` and hardcode `someIcon` - or do I need create a new component A' with the correct `@Input`?

Component A code looks like this:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'some-button',
  templateUrl: './some-button.component.html'
})
export class SomeButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() someIcon: string;
  @Input() someLabel: string;

  @Output() click: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

its template looking like:

```html
<button class="some-button">
  <span class="{{someIcon}}"></span>
  <span>{{someLabel}}</span>
</button>
```